# Caching Bings Maps Aerial Locally to make it draw faster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, bing-maps, arcgis-online-basemaps, basemap

When you add Bing Maps Aerial to your MXD, can you cache the basemap locally to make it draw faster?

If not, what other workaround can you do to make Bing Aerial draw faster?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcBruTile displays basemaps from OpenStreetMap, Bing,... and many others in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0/10.1/10.2.

- It also supports client side caching.
- TMS,WMT-s and WMS-C support

I suggest you to utilize this free tool, to use Bing maps with your ArcGis.

[ArcBlueTile on Codeplex](http://arcbrutile.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this problem all the time.  The best work-around I have found is to add the basemaps as an image service via the catalog.  The results are astonishingly fast compared to adding a basemap.  Use the following URL:  http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services

[image]

[image]

Additionally, make sure your data frame is using the default basemap projection `WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere`for the basemap or `GCS_WGS_1984` for the WMS.  You can do this by adding a basemap to a fresh map with no preexisting projection and then add your vector or raster data as layers.  Just make sure that the basemap is not projecting-on-the-fly to, for example, the UTM projected coordinate system of your vector data.

Comment: I can't see microsoft bing maps among Arcgis public services!